# Eclipse (Luna) + RemoteSystemExplorer - synchronization direction seams to opposite

Tags: synchronization, system, explorer, eclipse-luna

I have just /after some time to be honest/ set up the IDE for my project.
Part of it is Eclipse (LUNA) using RSE to synchronize PHP files with web server.

The problem is that it seems to me /or rather it is/ that RSE wants to work in the opposite direction.

An example:

I change file1 on workstation, then export it to the server using RSE.
Finally I have got (in the "Team Synchronizing" perspective):

1. file1 is being shown as changed on server (!)
2. GET is shadowed
3. Nothing to PUT ...

Did I miss something ??? Or made a mess ...

Comment: Solved it by changing the projects locations and re-exporting. Now it's working have no idea what it was ...

Comment: and one more comment .. It works ok but only if you "remove from the view" all project files on first synchronization, then do a std export (copy fiels to the server). Do not know why on FIRST synch RSE always wants to import files from server (even on export). This way you will clear flags so it work ok then.